# In jmeter, How to capture the script of authentication window?

Tags: jmeter

I also have the question that how to capture the script of authentication window (for e.g. username, password). If anyone knows the answer, Please help me out.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what you are trying to do and what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about pop-up window,then Jmeter doesn't support that.In case, you can try **Badboy** and import the test plan to Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can capture script by recording. At first, you will need to create `ThreadGroup` in TestPlan and than create `HTTPProxyServer` in WorkBench. 
ႊThen set port number in `Global Setting` box (eg.8911) and change your connection setting in IE as `localhost` in address and `8911` as in port.

Then you can start HTTPProxyServer in jmeter and run your application for login.
By doing it, you can capture login script but you may need to add expression for dynamic userId and password value to test.